# Any Advice or Tips For Giving Familiars Treats?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I have a few very closely related questions about feeding treats to familiars:

- How precious are treats in general, or specifically those of certain types?
- Can I undo giving treats to a familiar?  For instance, I don't want to max out Mitey with earlier treats if there will be much better ones later in the game.
- How can I tell if a treat will teach a new ability to a familiar? Will it be very clear or an outright surprise?

For what it's worth I did consider listing these as separate questions, but I didn't think they would be substantial enough to each stand on their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions, in order:

- Treats are common and cheap, so use them up without worry. Gems, on the other hand (these teach spells to familiars) are much more rare. Be wary of how you use these.
- You can't undo treats, but don't worry about it. You'll be able to tame another version of the critter if you don't like how you allocated points. Don't worry about keeping your starter familiars either, you'll find consistent upgrades along the way.
- As I mentioned above, gems are what teach abilities, not treats. It will be clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ni No Kuni Wiki,you need to look up the "Wizards Companion", under the section of familiar to find out what their favorite treats are, and feed their favorites accordingly.